# how to calculate sum values of different columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

table A,

| em_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | James |
| 2 | Ronnie |

table B,

| id | em_id | laptops | phones | Tablets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 |

this tables connected with a foreign key.

I wanna calculate the sum values of these fields (laptops, phones, Tablets). like this:

total calculations of items(materials)

| name | laptops | phones | Tablets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 5 | 7 | 7 |
| Ronnie | 4 | 6 | 4 |

Comment: This is common aggregation.

Answer (score 3):

After joining both tables you can use aggregation with group by.

```
select name, sum(laptops) laptops, sum(phones) phones, sum(tablets)tablets
from tableA a inner join tableB b
on a.em_id=b.em_id
group by name
```

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statemetns:

```
 create table tableA(em_id int, name varchar(100));
 insert into tableA values(1,   'James');
 insert into tableA values(2,   'Ronnie');     

 create table tableB(id int, em_id int, laptops int, phones int, Tablets int);
 insert into tableB values(1,   1,  3,  4,  5);
 insert into tableB values(2,   1,  2,  3,  2);
 insert into tableB values(3,   2,  2,  3,  2);
 insert into tableB values(4,   2,  2,  3,  2);
```

Query:

```
 select name, sum(laptops) laptops, sum(phones) phones, sum(tablets)tablets
 from tableA a inner join tableB b
 on a.em_id=b.em_id
 group by name
```

Output:

| name | laptops | phones | tablets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 5 | 7 | 7 |
| Ronnie | 4 | 6 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=daba7f3f4fa4700a51b89815030b7791)*

As @Tausif Shaikh mentioned, you surely can do it with subquery also.
Here goes the example:

```
 select (select name from tableA a where a.em_id=b.em_id)name, 
 sum(laptops) laptops, sum(phones) phones, sum(tablets)tablets   
 from tableB b   group by em_id
```

Output:

| name | laptops | phones | tablets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 5 | 7 | 7 |
| Ronnie | 4 | 6 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9d19fc65a4c51209ba40c473102f75b1)*

Comment: Please accept this answer by clicking the green check if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this using join or sub query

**1) Using join**

```
 select name, sum(laptops) laptops, sum(phones) phones, 
 sum(tablets)tablets
 from tableA a inner join tableB b
 on a.em_id=b.em_id
 group by name
```

**2) Using Sub Query**

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN 
( select em_id, sum(laptops) laptops, sum(phones) phones, sum(tablets)tablets
  from tableB
  group by em_id
) b
on a.em_id=b.em_id
```

Comment: If you really want to solve it with subquery then better option would be   `select (select name from tablea a where a.em_id=b.em_id)name, sum(laptops) laptops, sum(phones) phones, sum(tablets)tablets
  from tableB b
  group by em_id`